# What does “KCLErrorDomain error 2” mean in Shortcuts?

Tags: ios, ipad, photos, error, shortcuts-app

I made a shortcut on my iPad that takes an image as input, gets a bunch of info about it, then shows that info in a “Show Result” action. I keep getting a message that says “KCLErrorDomain error 2.” What does that mean and what can I do about it?
[image: A shortcut with a dialog box that says “The operation couldn’t be completed. (KCLErrorDomain error 2).”]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to fix your issue but I've seen similar errors before when developing location-based apps.

You said you're seeing a "kCLErrorDomain error 2" error. That's a [CoreLocation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation) framework error. More specifically, you're seeing "error 2". The error codes for `kCLErrorDomain` can be seen in the `CLError.h` header file of the framework:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, CLError) {
    kCLErrorLocationUnknown  = 0,         // location is currently unknown, but CL will keep trying
    kCLErrorDenied,                       // Access to location or ranging has been denied by the user
    kCLErrorNetwork,                      // general, network-related error
    kCLErrorHeadingFailure,               // heading could not be determined
    kCLErrorRegionMonitoringDenied,       // Location region monitoring has been denied by the user
    kCLErrorRegionMonitoringFailure,      // A registered region cannot be monitored
    kCLErrorRegionMonitoringSetupDelayed, // CL could not immediately initialize region monitoring
    kCLErrorRegionMonitoringResponseDelayed, // While events for this fence will be delivered, delivery will not occur immediately
    kCLErrorGeocodeFoundNoResult,         // A geocode request yielded no result
    kCLErrorGeocodeFoundPartialResult,    // A geocode request yielded a partial result
    kCLErrorGeocodeCanceled,              // A geocode request was cancelled
    kCLErrorDeferredFailed,               // Deferred mode failed
    kCLErrorDeferredNotUpdatingLocation,  // Deferred mode failed because location updates disabled or paused
    kCLErrorDeferredAccuracyTooLow,       // Deferred mode not supported for the requested accuracy
    kCLErrorDeferredDistanceFiltered,     // Deferred mode does not support distance filters
    kCLErrorDeferredCanceled,             // Deferred mode request canceled a previous request
    kCLErrorRangingUnavailable,           // Ranging cannot be performed
    kCLErrorRangingFailure,               // General ranging failure
    kCLErrorPromptDeclined,               // Authorization request not presented to user
};
```

If you're not familiar with the code above, it's fairly simple: `kCLErrorLocationUnknown` is assigned to 0 and the errors below that increment by 1. You're seeing an error code of 2, which maps to `kCLErrorNetwork`. The associated comment says that it's a "general, network-related error". While this is better than an unknown error it's sadly not specific enough to know the root cause.

From your screenshot it looks like you have good wifi but it might be worth checking your network.

Beyond that I'm not sure. I imagine that getting location info from the input probably extracts coordinates from the image's metadata and then uses the `CLGecoder`
interface to get the place name. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder) for `CLGeocoder` suggests it might throttle the number of requests per minute ("... in a typical situation, you should not send more than one geocoding request per minute"). The other answer here from [@F-erry](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/444469/115594) bypasses this by building a URL for getting location from coordinates instead.

But in short, that error suggests a general network error. Check your network and try the shorcut on different networks and devices.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue and on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/s1grsf/problems_extracting_location_from_an_image/) I found another person with a similar issue and no solution.

The KCLErrorDomain error might be triggered by an Apple location API. At this point I'm guessing, but it's a conclusion I draw based on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087660/error-domain-kclerrordomain-code-2-the-operation-couldn-t-be-completed-kclerr) I saw on stackoverflow. Where somebody is writing Swift code and gets the KCLErrorDomain error. The answers for that particular question suggests a network error or API throttle.

In my Shortcut I can exclude network error or api throttling.

That leaves another cause with the location API still in place. So I experimented a bit more and noticed that the location information from a picture or video is different from other location information e.g. de location information you can get from the weather service.

As such this KCLErrorDomain might be a bug in Shortcuts because the location information cannot be correctly processed by the API and this is something only apple can fix.

for future reference: I'm currently on ios 15.6

I found a workaround

It's not very fast, but it works.
I could not make it work without the Get distance step although this step seems pointless for the desired result.

[image]

Comment: Hi, your answer is a little misleading. It looks like the error may not be a bug but a network and throttling issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/325114)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).